# Best way to duplicate block of html after copying it with yat command

Tags: vim

I have small html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Prompt on 3rd line `<div class="col-sm-10">` on letter m.
Now I type `yat` to copy this div.
What's the best way to paste it below this div, so I get:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

For now I'm doing: `yat` `jj` `o` `<esc>` `p` `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With built-in commands, I would do:

```
vatVyP
```

The `V` turns the characterwise selection into a linewise one, so it can be pasted as-is. I paste above with `P` to avoid moving.

#### Plugin solution

With my [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140), there's a visual mode duplicate mapping `]d`, giving the short:

```
vat]d
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

```
vatVy'>p
```

#### Explanation

- Visually select the tag (`vat`) linewise (`V`)
- Yank/copy the text (`y`)
- Move to end of the visual selection (`'>`)
- Put/paste the block (`p`)